# PHP/SQL doesn't fetch all children from parent

Tags: php, mysql

I created this code for a dropdown navigation menu. I have 2 tables in my database, one for parentitems and the other one for childitems. The parents getting out correctly, but the childitems won't.

The problem is, I only get one parent and one child at a time, or I get totally nothing.

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db=mysql_select_db('navigation',$con);
    $query="select * from nav";

    $run=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
        $m_id=$row['m_id'];
        $m_title=$row['m_title'];
        $child_query="select * from nav_child where parent_id='$m_id'";
        $run_child=mysql_query($child_query);

        while($row_child=mysql_fetch_array($run_child)) {
           $child_id=$row_child['nav_id'];
           $child_title=$row_child['child_title'];
           echo"<ul>
                  <li><a href='menu.php'>$m_title</a>
                   <ul> 
                    <li><a href='menu.php'>$child_title</a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your html

```
while(mainquery) { 
   echo '<ul>'          <-----note the location
   while (subquery) {
      echo '<li>subquery 1 stuff</li>'
   }
   echo '</ul>'         <-----note the location
}
```

You're outputting it entirely in your subquery section, so EVERY child row gets its own complete `<ul><li>...</li></ul>` tag set.

Comment: Thanks #Marc Can you please set the code properly?

Comment: Thanks alot Marc have done with your help... :)